# Pesquisa em Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, algoritmo-de-busca, dicionário

Tenho o seguinte dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ObterCodigo()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
           {"18", "Teste"},     
           {"19", "Teste"},
           {"02", "AAA"},
           {"03", "AAA"},
           {"109", "BBB"},
           {"157", "BBB"},
       };
}
```

Gostaria que minha combobox buscasse apenas os valores de "AAA". Tem como fazer?

Comment: Por buscar, você quer dizer que ela apresentasse apenas estes dois valores iguais (`"AAA"`) ?

Comment: Queria fazer uma busca por "AAA" e retornar os valores "02" e "03"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer apenas retornar as Keys cujo valor é "AAA". Eu faria isso com LINQ, disponível a partir do .NET 3.5 (se você pudesse especificar qual você usa seria melhor).

```
var valores = from item in ObterCodigo()
              where item.Value == "AAA"
              select item.Key;
```

Isso retorna apenas as chaves. Se quiser retornar o `KeyValuePair<string, string>`, basta selecionar `item` ao invés de `item.Key`.

Outro jeito, também com o LINQ, é:

```
var valores = ObterCodigo()
              .Where(item => item.Value == "AAA")
              .Select(item => item.Key);
```

Note que isso retorna uma instância de `IEnumerable<string>`. Dependendo de qual implementação de `ComboBox` você esteja usando, você precisará enumerá-lo primeiro. Para isso, basta usar a função `ToList()` no retorno.

**Bônus:** Caso você não possa usar o LINQ (seja por estar usando uma versão antiga do Framework ou porque seu chefe não deixa -- já aconteceu comigo -- segue uma versão sem ele -- bem parecida com como seria em Java):

```
Dictionary<string, string> codigos = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair item in ObterCodigo())
    if (item.Value == "AAA")
        codigos.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
```

Comment: Usando o `Diagnostics.StopWatch` vi que o segundo código na sua resposta é muito ( mas muito mesmo ) mais rápido. Mas não deixa de ser a resposta certa.

Comment: Hmm, não sabia que usar o syntatic sugar do LINQ causava problemas de desempenho. Valeu pela observação.

Comment: Provavelmente porque uma expressao de LINQ nao e realizada immediatemente. Experimente com ".ToList()" juntado no fim da expressao.

Comment: @mdisibio O método `Select` também tem a execução atrasada. Os dois trechos, teoricamente, fazem exatamente a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode montar um dicionário a parte só para isso.

Você pode populá-lo da seguinte forma:

```
Dictionary<string, string> newDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> oldDic = ObterCodigo();
foreach (string key in oldDic.Keys)
{
    if (oldDic[key] == "AAA") newDic.add(key, oldDic[key]);
}
```

Ao final do trecho acima, o dicionário `newDic` conterá apenas os itens desejados.

Comment: Tem certeza que uma `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` é uma alternativa melhor que `Dictionary<string, string>`? Em essência, o dictionary já faz o trabalho de uma lista de `KeyValuePair`s.

Comment: @AndréLeria tem razão. Vou reescrever a resposta.