# Obter objeto em array por descrição no index

Tags: c#, .net, collection

É possível usar a propriedade de um objeto como índice de um *array*, como descrito no exemplo abaixo?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myObjectArray = new MyObject[]{
            new MyObject("item1", "valor1", 1, 1.1),
            new MyObject("item2", "valor2", 2, 2.2),
            new MyObject("item3", "valor3", 3, 3.3)
        };

        // Para obter o valor do objeto com o Name "item2", preciso encontra-lo através do índice:
        Console.WriteLine(myObjectArray[1].Value);

        // O que eu gostaria de fazer é passar o valor da propriedade 'Name' de um determinado objeto como index, 
        // e poder acessar todas as propriedades dele, da seguinte forma:
        Console.WriteLine(myObjectArray["item2"].Value);
    }
}

public class MyObject {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public int Prop1 {get; set;}
    public double Prop2 {get; set;}

    public MyObject (string name, string valueParam, int prop1, double prop2){
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = valueParam;
        this.Prop1 = prop1;
        this.Prop2 = prop2;
    }
}
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AqCE6q)

Comment: Precisa ser *array* ou pode mudar a estrutura de dados usada? Os elementos nela precisam estar em alguma ordem específica? Pode ter elementos repetidos no primeiro membro do objeto? Pode separar esse membro do resto do objeto?

Comment: Use um dicionario de dados

Comment: Tenho preferência por `array`, mas se não for possível também posso avaliar outras opções. Bem, atualmente não preciso dos elementos em ordem específica, mas existe alguma solução que possibilite ordena-los? Não entendi muito bem as ultimas perguntas @Maniero

Comment: Como eu poderia usar um dicionário de dados nesse caso @VirgilioNovic ?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues eu fiz um exemplo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece que um [dicionário](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1) é o suficiente para o que precisa.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var dicionario = new Dictionary<string, MyObject> {
            ["item1"] = new MyObject("item1", "valor1", 1, 1.1),
            ["item2"] = new MyObject("item2", "valor2", 2, 2.2),
            ["item3"] = new MyObject("item3", "valor3", 3, 3.3)
        };
        Console.WriteLine(dicionario["item2"].Value);
    }
}

public class MyObject {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public int Prop1 {get; set;}
    public double Prop2 {get; set;}

    public MyObject (string name, string valueParam, int prop1, double prop2){
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = valueParam;
        this.Prop1 = prop1;
        this.Prop2 = prop2;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/8tvYlR). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C0xSpo). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Dictionary.cs).

O dicionário tem tempo de acesso praticamente idêntico ao do *array*, (pelo menos a complexidade de acesso é essencialmente a mesma (O(1) em caso típico, mas O(n) no pior caso, que na prática nunca chega nem perto de acontecer).

É importante notar que se mandar listar todos os elementos eles podem vir em qualquer ordem e se tentar pegar um elemento pelo seu índice pode não vir o que está esperando, o algoritmo não é estável para dar esta possibilidade, mesmo que funciona em um teste básico, não funcionará em outro caso, e o mesmo teste que funcionou pode não funcionar mais se mudar o `Dictionary` ou o algoritmo de *hash*  do objeto usado como chave. Não há garantias de nada.

Se precisa de ordem use um [`SortedDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1). Ele é ligeira mais lento, mas na maioria dos casos muda muito pouco e há muitos casos que ele pode ser mais rápido que o dicionário. Ele tem complexidade O(log n) que é muito próxima de O(1). Tem casos que a fórmula de *hash* pode acrescer *overhaed* que faz ser pior que o acesso à árvore do `SortedDictionary`. O pior caso dele é O(log n), então ele é muito mais previsível e evita certos tipos de ataques de DOS que o *hash* permite. E por causa da localidade de referência prejudicada a tabela *hash* do `Dictionary` pode acessar os dados mais lentamente por não aproveitar bem o cache.

Se tiver que garantir que os valores das chaves não se repitam [pode usar um `Set`, tem algumas opções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29226/101).

Tem uma outra opção, a [`KeyedCollection`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56001/101) que te dá a vantagem da lista e a vantagem do dicionário ao mesmo tempo, talvez seja o mais adequado para o que deseja. Ela usa um dos membros do objeto como chave de forma implícita.

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero eu não conhecia o `Dictionary`, e também gostei muito do seu código, está bem limpo e estruturado, meus parabéns!

Comment: A opção do `SortedDictionary` foi ótima! Com certeza usarei isso.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues note que `SortedDictionary` é uma implementação de árvore rubro-negra na maioria dos casos. O acesso é **pior** que um dicionário normal e acaba perdendo performance pra inserir e pra excluir elementos. A opção é boa, claro. Mas é necessário ter cautela na hora de escolher.

Comment: @LINQ mais ou menos, melhorei o texto para explicar isso. Tem um problema na sua resposta, leia a minha atual.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues coloquei mais uma opção. Aquela minha última pergunta no comentário era sobre isto, no caso do dicionário normal a chave fica redundante.

Answer (score 2):

O que você está procurando é uma estrutura de dados chamada de `Dictionary`, ela nada mais é que uma tabela *hash*.

Uma tabela *hash* é uma estrutura de dados linear com complexidade de acesso constante, então não há muita perda de *perfomance* ao trocar um *array* por um *dicionário*. O acesso de ambos tem complexidade O(1). É claro que a inserção em um tabela *hash* é mais demorada que a inserção diretamente num *array*, porém, usando um dicionário há a vantagem de buscar pelas chaves, que são previamente definidas por você.

Você pode aproveitar os métodos de extensão do Linq e fazer um acesso pelo *index*, como pede o seu primeiro exemplo.

Note que não há nenhuma garantia de que a ordem da estrutura seja a mesma ordem de inserção, isso porque o `Dictionary` mantem uma ordenação própria.

Veja um exemplo::

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dicionario = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>()
        {
            { "item1", new MyObject{ Name = "item1", Value = "valor1" } },
            { "item2", new MyObject{ Name = "item2", Value = "valor2" } },
            { "item3", new MyObject{ Name = "item3", Value = "valor3" } }               
        };      

        // Acesso por index:
        Console.WriteLine(dicionario.Values. ElementAt(1));

        // Acesso pela chave
        Console.WriteLine(dicionario["item2"].Value);
    }
}

public class MyObject 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public int Prop1 {get; set;}
    public double Prop2 {get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @LINQ eu não conhecia o `Dictionary`. Realmente ele me atenderá bem, e obrigado também por já me adiantar detalhes sobre ele.

Answer (score 2):

> É possível usar a propriedade de um objeto como índice de um array, como descrito no exemplo abaixo?

## SIM

Eu gosto mais de trabalhar com Collection List.
Acho mais elegante, e não precisa criar um "indice" como no dicionário, vc pode usar o nome do seu próprio objeto, ou o ID, como preferir.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var minhaColecao = new MinhaCollection();
        minhaColecao.Add(new MeuObjeto { Nome = "A", Valor = 10.0m, Data = DateTime.Now });
        minhaColecao.Add(new MeuObjeto { Nome = "B", Valor = 2.0m, Data = DateTime.Now });
        minhaColecao.Add(new MeuObjeto { Nome = "C", Valor = 340.5m, Data = DateTime.Now });
    
        var objA = minhaColecao["A"];    
    
        Console.WriteLine($"Nome: {objA.Nome} Valor: {objA.Valor} ");
    }
}

public class MinhaCollection : List<MeuObjeto>
{
    public MeuObjeto this[string nome]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FirstOrDefault(meuObjeto => meuObjeto.Nome == nome);
        }
    }
}

public class MeuObjeto
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pJDLcl).

Comment: Nesse caso você sai de uma complexidade de busca constante pra uma complexidade linear. Uma solução péssima pra quem se preocupa com performance de busca. Embora, eu ache uma solução muito melhor pra casos normais.

Comment: A pergunta é "como usar a propriedade de um objeto como índice de um array". É isso que mostrei como fazer. E outra, isso é uma abstração, dá pra usar com Dictionary tbm.

Comment: Opção interessante, gostei de poder implementar da forma como quiser o método `get`, mas essa questão de performance citada pelo @LINQ é importante, ainda não tenho base suficiente para falar do assunto, mas estarei pesquisando. Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Thiago, eu li o que a pergunta diz. Eu deixei meu comentário pra que as pessoas que cheguem aqui tenham noção disso, não pra criticar. Eu mesmo disse que acho uma solução ótima pra maioria dos casos simples do dia-a-dia (inclusive, muitas implementações do WinForms fazem uso disto). Sobre ser uma abstração: mesmo que você tente fazer a implementação com `IDictionary` a performance vai continuar a mesma, não é a presença ou ausência de uma _keyword_ que traz performance e sim a implementação. É bem possível implementar `List` e ter acesso constante como numa HashTable.

Answer (score 2):

O mais fácil seria adicionar uma referência para o Linq

```
using System.Linq;
```

E e fazer a consulta de acordo com o atributo que desejar.

```
Console.WriteLine(myObjectArray.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "item2").Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Faça com [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), ***exemplo***:

***Classe Base:***

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public int Prop1 {get; set;}
    public double Prop2 {get; set;}

    public MyObject (string name, string valueParam, int prop1, double prop2)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = valueParam;
        this.Prop1 = prop1;
        this.Prop2 = prop2;
    }
}
```

---

***Dicionario***

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> myObjectArray = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();
myObjectArray.Add("Item1", new MyObject("item1", "valor1", 1, 1.1));
myObjectArray.Add("Item2", new MyObject("item2", "valor2", 2, 2.2));
myObjectArray.Add("Item3", new MyObject("item3", "valor3", 3, 3.3));
```

---

***Recuperação***

```
var dado = myObjectArray["Item1"]
```

***Acessando valores***:

```
dado.Name
dado.Value
dado.Prop1
dado.Prop2
```

---

[Um exemplo ONLINE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HPM7OO) *que pode usado como base no seu código*.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Classe Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Pesquisa em Dictionary](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2654/pesquisa-em-dictionary)
- [Propriedade Dictionary.IDictionary.Item (Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb302460(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Muito obrigado @VirgilioNovic eu não conhecia o `Dictionary`. Realmente ele me atenderá bem.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Vlw